# How to reset my text cursor after changing locale?

Tags: windows, firefox, locale

After changing the locale of my windows laptop to "Arabic (Saudi Arabia)", the text cursor displayed when typing changed from the usual vertical bar to a bar with a small protrusion near the top, as seen at the right end of the text in this cropped screenshot:

[image: My weird cursor]

Changing the locale back to "English (UK)" did not revert this change. How can I get the regular "bar" cursor back?

Comment: `Start` > `Control Panel` > `Mouse` > `Pointers`?

Comment: That  small protrusion near the top is a flag indicating keyboard direction (`left-to-right` vs. `right-to-left`) perhaps. Unfortunately, I do not know how to change it in Windows not having any RTL installed. However, it may be application specific like in `EditPad`...

Comment: Oh jeez, it was application-specific, it only happened in Firefox. How did I miss that? Posting the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is to indicate the text direction (left-to-right), and was displaying because the Firefox about:config option `bidi.browser.ui` was set to `true` (presumably Firefox does this automatically when it detects that you're using certain languages which can be right-to-left, and doesn't switch it back when you're using English). Changing the setting to `false` returned the cursor to the "vertical bar" shape that I'm used to.